# ASUS TUF VG27AQL1A will not run at its advertised refresh rate of 170hz

Tags: display, graphics-card, windows-11, refresh-rate

I bought the ASUS TUF VG27AQL1A recently after finding it for a good price. It's advertised as 1440p+170hz, but when I go to the Windows display settings, the maximum framerate option is 144hz. Even after setting the output resolution to 1080p and even 720p, no higher refresh rate options appeared.

I looked around and found that it needs to be overclocked to reach 170hz, but I can't figure out how to do that. I tried using the Nvidia Control Panel to create a custom resolution profile for 2560x1440 170hz, but when I select "test", the screen just goes black for about 15 seconds and reverts to 144hz. Any tips on how to get it to 170hz?

I am using DisplayPort (the VG27AQL1A uses DP 1.2) and running Windows 11. My video card is an RTX 4060ti. Below is a screenshot of the custom resolution profile I attempted to set.

[image: custom resolution]

Comment: Have you looked through the on screen menu system for the display? Some monitors consider >144Hz to be an "overclocked" mode that needs to be specifically enabled. I have a 165Hz panel that defaults to 144Hz unless you enable it.

Comment: That's a great suggestion; I did check the on screen menu and it looks like there are some gaming options which might contain an overclock option, but they're greyed out and not able to be selected. I'm not sure why that might be.

Comment: 170MHz is hardware dependent.  “Select graphics cards/GPUs can support 170Hz graphics source output (via DisplayPort).” The monitor only supports 170 MHz at 2560x1440 no other resolution is supported. Check the manual. Overclocking is disabled unless specific conditions are achieved. **Additionally make sure your running 23H2**

Comment: I have looked through the manual, there's nothing about specific conditions for overclocking. As stated in the post, I have a 4060ti, which supports 1440p at 170hz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular display only supports up to 170Hz when panel overclocking is enabled on the display itself. You must enable the overclocking option with the monitor's OSD menu. When done appropriately, the faster refresh rate option will become available in the NVIDIA Control Panel's Display/Change resolution menu. A Custom resolution is generally not required.

The steps for accessing the display OSD's overclocking feature are in the manual on starting on page 21: https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/LCD%20Monitors/VG27AQ1A/VG27AQL1A_VG27AQ1A_English.pdf?model=VG27AQL1A

If the option is missing/disabled, then you may wish to reset the display back to factory defaults, and then perform a "full AC" reset where the AC power cable is disconnected for several seconds.

Comment: Also note that 170Hz may not be supported - while "most" panels in this display may reach 170Hz, some may not be capable which is the purpose of selling this feature as an "overclock." If your display stays blank or flickers after you enable the faster refresh rate in the NVIDIA Control Panel, use the OSD to disable the Overclock feature or choose a lower overclocked refresh rate.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. After checking the OSD, the option for overclocking was visible but it was greyed out and unable to be selected. However, after I reset the display to factory defaults, the option became available, and selecting the overclocking option on the display caused it to appear as an option in Windows. Thanks!